# Why is it necessary to cast an enumeration element to a String when printing it out?

Tags: java, string, casting, enumeration

```
Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String paramName = (String) paramNames.nextElement();
    out.print(paramName);
}
```

From the above code I don't understand why the typecast of `paramNames.nextElement()` to String is necessary. Can some one explain this?
When I pass the parameter name from a form it is already in a String, then why do we use `(String)`?

Comment: Have you tried Enumeration<String>?

Comment: What java version are you using, if you are using java 6, then you can use Enumeration<String> then type casting to string will not be required.

Comment: Also, `enum` and `Enumeration` are quite different things - beware of mixups.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Ankit or using Java 5.0.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: It was not Enumeration<String> in java 5.0 - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames%28%29

Comment: @Ankit Good point, it is easy to get J2SE 5.0 and J2EE 5.0 confused.

Answer (score 5):

`Enumeration` is a generic type, and should typically be used with a proper generic parameter.  For example an `Enumeration` of `String`s:

```
Enumeration<String> paramNames = ...;
```

This makes the signature of the `nextElement()` method look like this:

```
public String nextElement();
```

The reason they cast to a `String` is because that without a generic parameter, the compiler treats it as if you'd typed:

```
Enumeration<Object>
```

So the return type of `nextElement()` becomes `Object`, and you can't just assign an object to the `String` variable `paramName`.

Of course, if `request.getParameterNames()` doesn't return `Enumeration<String>`, but just `Enumeration`, then you can't do any better than that.

Answer (score 0):

Because `paramName` is a `String`, you're telling the compiler to trust you that you know what you're doing and `paramNames.nextElement()` will definitely return a `String`. Your code will compile but might crash during runtime if `paramNames.nextElement()` will have an object of type that cannot be cast to `String`. Note that if you have `Enumeration<String>` then the cast is redundant.

Comment: getParameterNames return an Enumeration<String> in java 6. -- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames%28%29 whereas in java 5 it was just Enumeration, i.e. of Objects http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames%28%29